# Do I need to handle Dummy variable trap manually in Regression or sklearn will do it?

Tags: machine-learning, dummy-variable, one-hot-encoding

I know that we have to one-hot encode categorical data before training machine Learning algorithm. but my question is do we need to remove one column manually or sklearn will do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to drop one column also for non-binary categorical features to avoid multi-collinearity, which might cause problems for linear models. It is as easy as providing `drop_first=True` argument to `pd.get_dummies()`. It seems that `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` doesn't have a simple interface to do this and anyway its usage is complicated, as categorical features have to be encoded into `int`'s beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle Dummy variable trap manually in Regression.
We need to remove one column manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `drop` parameter in the `OneHotEncoder`:

```
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(drop='first'), [3])], remainder='passthrough')
```

[Here is the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder)

This makes the prediction a little more accurate.

Answer (score -3):

There is no sense in removing a column with `nunique` count greater than 2. As each column will represent an instance of a dummy variable. I assume that you are one-hot encoding a binary featured column. Instead, use sklearn's label encoder.